# deleting the same names with different scores? and redoing the whole thing with encapsulation?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

needed help with this part of my code that.. i'm writing a code for a hangman game.. and after somebody wins and I calculate their scores.. I sort them based on their scores and print it.. but I don't wanna have the same name with different scores.. I mean if the same person played again and won, and if that person's score is higher than before, I don't wanna add any new names and replace that person's score..
I use an ArrayList for saving the names and scores.. after anybody wins, i add the name and then the score to the ArrayList.. but when I wanna replace the scores for the same name, I seem to have a problem..
and also I know that my code is kinda stupid this way.. just wanna know the problem..

```
            // here I add the name and the score to the end of my rankings ArrayList..
            rankings.add(name);
            rankings.add(finalScore);
            if (rankings.size() > 2) {
                for (int i = 0; i < rankings.size() - 2; i++) {
                    if (rankings.get(i).equals(rankings.get(rankings.size() - 2))) {
                        if (rankings.get(i + 1).compareTo(rankings.get(rankings.size() - 1)) == -1) {
                            rankings.set(i + 1, rankings.get(rankings.size() - 1));
                            rankings.remove(rankings.size() - 1);
                            rankings.remove(rankings.size() - 2);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

also.. can you help me redo the whole thing in another way.. I mean instead of adding the name and the score each time separately.. I wanna make an ArrayList of objects that each object contains a name and a score.. someway that I can check for duplicate names.. and then sort them.. thank you.. and sorry for messy code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should encapsulate `name` and `score` in a separate class, e.g. `Player`. This will help you to track players by name and compare them by score or any other field that can be added to `Player` class:

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    private int score;

    public Player(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

Than you should operate with `List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();`, populate the list with data and retrieve & modify its values as you need.